# exec not returning matches in arr[1] - n

Tags: javascript, regex, exec

I have a regex that I'm using to try to get some values from the `getComputedStyle` object. I would expect that when I run it against `exec` at each iteration starting at index 1 my matches would be located, but at each iteration two new elements are added to `myArray` and elements set before are now undefined.

```
var styleAsDashedStr = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("container")).cssText;
var styleRe = /(?:;\s?(background.*?)\:\s?(.*?);)|(?:;\s?(font.*?)\:\s?(.*?);)|(?:;\s?(border.*?)\:\s?(.*?);)|(?:;\s?(margin.*?)\:\s?(.*?);)|(?:;\s?(padding.*?)\:\s?(.*?);)/g;
//var individuallySetStyles = styleAsDashedStr.match(styleRe);

var myArray;
while ((myArray = styleRe.exec(styleAsDashedStr)) !== null) {
    console.log(myArray);
}
```

First iteraction

```
0: "; background-blend-mode: normal;"
1: "background-blend-mode"
2: "normal"
3: undefined
4: undefined
5: undefined
6: undefined
7: undefined
8: undefined
9: undefined
10: undefined
```

And subsequent iterations have two elements defined, but the other 8 are not. Is there a way to get an array where elements one and two are the current captures?

Comment: It's really not clear what you expect. Your capturing groups are all separated by `|` groups, so on any single `.exec()` call only one of those outer non-capturing groups will match.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah I realize that now. Ideally I would capture each of them. Any ideas on how I could accomplish that? Thanks.

Comment: Just iterate like you're doing, but pluck out the matched property name and value and store them in a separate object (or array or whatever you like).

Comment: @Pointy I'm not sure I explained myself well. I get that storing them in an object will be best, but I just want to match the entire set of words. But the regex is failing after all the `background`s are stored in that object. Border, font, etc fail. Do you know how I could ensure I match those strings as well? Thanks again.

Comment: Well your regex insists on there being a semicolon followed by at most one character of whitespace before each property. What does the actual string look like?

Comment: ... hold on let me update my answer; I've got an idea about what may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accumulate an object to  hold the rules you find:

```
var myArray, rules = {};
while ((myArray = styleRe.exec(styleAsDashedStr)) !== null) {
    console.log(myArray);
    if (myArray[1] && myArray[2])
      rules[myArray[1]] = myArray[2];
}
```

That way you'd end up with an object that contained all the matched properties.

You could simplify your regex too (as in the answer Barmar just gave while I was editing :).

*edit* — a problem with your pattern is that your "stanzas" both begin *and end* with a `;`. When you match something, the match will involve both the starting semicolon *and the one that comes after it*.  The next match will start *after* the matched semicolon, so the parts of the patterns that require a leading semicolon will fail.

Answer (score 2):

Use a single capture group for all the style names, not separate groups.

```
var styleRe = /\b((?:background|font|border|margin|padding).*?)\:\s?([^;]*?)/g;
```

Note that you shouldn't match `;` at the beginning and end, because this will cause it to skip the first style (since there's no `;` before it) and then every other style (because matching the `;` at the end of one will prevent matching the `;` at the beginning of the next one). I've avoided this completely by using `[^;]*` instead of `.*?` at the end.